# WordPress, не получается включить в страницу диаграмму Visualizer

Tags: wordpress

В библиотеке имеется 5 диаграмм, но не получается их включить в конкретную страницу.  [image: Может быть, они не активированы?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

прочитайте, что там написано). Нужно просто скопировать шорткод диаграммы и вставить его шорткодом на странице. Если что, шорткод диагрымы написан под ней